# Ultra low consumption white LED flasher

Tags: led

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIqoKd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I need an LED flasher circuit to operate inside small model lighthouses. Ideally the flash needs to be white and the battery needs to be physically small but last for years.

Conventional wisdom (and holy writ,) is that you should not put a resistor in series with the Vdd pin of a CMOS logic circuit however I have working before me a highly efficient LED flasher circuit that does just this.

The circuit (that I rather stumbled upon,) uses one 4001 IC. The IC has two gates configured as a conventional astable and uses the remaining two gates as inverters in series which provide anti-phase outputs.   With no resistor in the supply line and a supply voltage of 9 Volts this part of the circuit consumes 170 microamperes which is not surprising for a CMOS oscillator at this supply voltage.  This is unsustainable for a small battery to supply for any length of time. The oscillator cycle period is 12 seconds.

With a massive 1 Meg Ohm resistor between the supply line and the Vdd pin the circuit still runs but now with a cycle time of 5 seconds. The circuit now consumes around one microampere and, incredibly, the 'On' voltage available at the output of the two inverters is above 6 Volts and is available to feed two 2N7000 FETs with no need for level shifting. The two FETs are wired in series and fed in anti-phase so that when one is switched 'on' the other is 'off'. At the source/drain junction between them the output voltage cycles between 0 and 7.1 Volt.

The output of the two FETs is connected to two white LEDs connected back to back in parallel and these in turn to an electrolytic 'bucket' capacitor which is connected to ground. When the output goes high it charges the capacitor via one LED giving a flash and when the output goes low then the capacitor discharges via the second LED giving another flash.  The two LEDs can be physically mounted close together so as to appear to be a single light source and to fulfil the requirements of a model lighthouse.

The intensity of the flashes can be varied by selecting different values of the bucket capacitor and I have tried values from 4.7nF which gives a just discernable flash and up to 47 microfarad at which value the flashes are very bright. At 4.7nF the current consumption is 1 microampere and at 47 microfarad the current consumption is 21 microampere. These values are roughly one thousandth what would be normal for a 555 circuit and would reduce further with longer cycle times.

The knotty problem of measuring such low currents is solved here by having the 100 Ohm sense resistor with a parallel 3 Farad super capacitor in the supply line. (This capacitor is one that I have to hand--a smaller super capacitor would probably do.) After a lengthy period, (say half an hour for very low current values,) the voltage across the resistor can be measured with a suitable millivolt meter and the current calculated. These two components can be removed when not required.

My question is "I would like to think that this circuit could have widespread application but is it just **too** outrageous to recommend?" (I should add that my qualifications lay outside electronics but having had a ham radio callsign for nearly sixty years I have a long history of cruelty towards and misuse of innocent components.)

Comment: Have you accounted for the leakage current through your capacitors, particularly the 3F capacitor? This may add significant error to your current estimates.

Comment: A one megohm resistor there is certainly quite unconventional. If it works, and this is a one-off, I imagine you're fine, but if it's a production device I'd say don't do it; try to find another way to get such low power.

Comment: There are much simpler and more efficient ways to do this. Can you define the Candella intensity , minimum number of LEDs and expected duration of the pulse needed , or like a Xenon flash? then one can determine the optimal battery power to sustain years of usage. with wireless rechargeable abilities even.

Comment: That is a real simple circuit, try bread-boarding it.  In my experience, spice simulators don't simulate correctly when you do such things to the power pins of logic chips.  Also, they don't simulate capacitor leakage and absorption well. Experiment!  PS. since you don't have current limiting on the LEDs, you'll need to make sure that the energy pulse is small enough to prevent over heating the die.

Comment: This circuit is **very unconventional** and also relies on components that are there but not in the schematic! For example: how can C1 charge/discharge? If you look at the schematic one side of C1 is connected to an input so no current can flow. So why can it still work? Because C1 charges/discharges through the ESD diodes that are between all pins of the CD4001 and its supply pins. That probably also explains why despite the 1M resistor in the supply this thing still "works". I think it is designed in a poor way. There is no reason why it would perform better than a more conventional circuit.

Comment: 9V current limiting is wasted in the battery ESR so your LED driver will be wasting up to 6V out of 9. i.e. 30% efficient.  ALso when you have a slow rise time in the CMOS input with low gain, the outputs will be in cross conduction mode with < 1 kOhm  load pulse  drain. WOrse yet the external FETS if not carefully selected will also be in cross-conduction mode with < 10 Ohms across the battery during crossover charging up the cap.

Comment: Similar to "Low-frequency oscillator draws only 500nA", EDN, Sep 2, 1993. The circuit given there used a CD4007.

Comment: Profuse apologies but the two inputs to NOR 1 should be joined, the join was there but I must have inadvertantly erased it.  As far as I can see it is not possible to go in and re-edit the circuit.

Comment: It is indeed possible to edit out mistakes and I have now done this. Please excuse my inexperience with CircuitLab where it is all too easy to erase a wire when manipulating something else.

Comment: @LionelSear I can provide a 9V circuit that produces 20 Hz at \$7\:\mu\text{W}\$ on a 9 V battery using only three cheap BJTs. But it's just a relaxation oscillator.  At 3 Hz, this drops to \$1.4\:\mu\text{W}\$. It will take some care (dead-bug?) construction to keep down leakage and some unusually large resistor values to get out to one pulse per 12 s. I've never tried that. But the circuit is robust and actually designed to work well. Still, it's just the oscillator and an LED with a short pulse through it. I use it with a 6N137 to create solid output drive, for now.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson Re the possible leakage in the 3 Farad capacitor.  I was rather hoping that at the level of a milliVolt or so leakage will be very low but I cannot justify this or measure it with my home equipment.  I have also used the method to measure the current draw of battery clocks which have a very short pulse once per second and the results do make sense.  The method certainly allows for comparison between clocks.

Comment: @Sunnyskyguy EE75 To address one point for now. Re the possibility of cross conduction in the FET's I was concerned at the possibility but can only say that it is not showing up in the current measurements. With the LED's disconnected I am measuring a current draw of 1 micro Amp which is accounted for by the 4001.

Comment: so what is your question? is it reliable?

Comment: My overall question is in the wisdom of recommending this circuit to home enthusiasts.  There are vast numbers of model lighthouses purchased and built and many will want to see them light up.  Putting a 1 meg Ohm resistor in the Vdd line of a CMOS IC is a pretty drastic or even daft thing to do but in this case it does, with a 4.7 microFarad bucket capacitor, result in a circuit that consumes 4 micro Amps and a stack of three 2032 lithium button cells should last over 6 years. Before submitting a project on the 'Instructables' website for instance I would welcome any input from professionals.

Comment: 5V 3F SuperCaps are often spec'd with 20uA leakage current @ $10 which may cause a problem as well, the CMOS characteristics have a wide tolerance and I am not so sure this would work over the worst case. for all types of CMOS and all types of supercaps.  Leakage is temperature dependent and is rated only after 100hrs of burn-in. I hope you are using Iv>20 Cd type LEDs.

Comment: @Aaron  I have now tried the circuit with a bucket capacitor of 200 uF. Flash is very bright and the LED's  survive. Your point is valid and perhaps with larger bucket caps a small ballast resistor might be a good idea. With larger caps the LED's continue to emit light at a very low level after the flash as the last bit of charge leaks away.

Comment: The LED's I am using are catalogued as Ultra High Bright White 12000mcd min. 3.2Vf 20mA.

Comment: Many thanks to everyone for their input.  I think now that this is somewhat of a curiosity best not recommended without a health warning. However the hobby enthusiast willing to try it out on a  breadboard first could achieve useful results from a handful of cheap widely available components.

Comment: The Texas Instruments LP5660 (http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lp5560.pdf) might be just the solution for this application. With the default ramp, blink and current settings (0.53 sec ramp-up, 0.5 sec on, 0.53 sec ramp-down, 1.6 sec off, at 5.3mA) a couple of 2032 button cells (6V total) should be good for months of operation, going by the datasheet. Program it to a lower current, lower ramp times, and a longer off time, and a year or two will be possible.

Yes, the BGA package is a challenge for most hobbyists, but that's an opportunity for someone to leverage as a cottage industry.

Comment: @LionelSear What did you wind up recommending? After reading all this, I still don't know what you wanted as the pulse period or the pulse duration for the white LED. But assuming 100% efficiency to the LED (impossible), I find you'll need \$I_\text{LED}\cdot V_\text{LED}\cdot t_\text{WIDTH}\cdot \frac{365.2425\:\text{days}}{t_\text{PERIOD}\:\text{(seconds)}}\$ in Joules per year from the battery.

Comment: @jonk I was looking for input from the professional community with regard to misusing CMOS in this way and some disapprove! The pulse period just needs to be appropriate for a lighthouse and a flash every few seconds is fine. I just experiment with a solderless breadboard to find suitable vales for R and C. I stand by this circuit and have now reproduced it a number of times, the latest being my take on the ubiquitous flower pot lighthouse which flashes away outside oblivious to rain and gales and with six hardwired AA cells the assembly should run until they corrode.

Comment: @LionelSear I'm glad to hear everything is fine. (It had been a while and I had been wondering -- although I'll admit that by now I'd forgotten about it, entirely.)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seeks an opinion.  We all know the chip is being atypically used, you claim it works for your situation but there is no conclusive answer possible to your solicitation of general opinions.  Questions seeking opinion-based answers are off topic as a matter of site rules.

Comment: As Tony noted, use of a 9V battery MUST waste most of the battery energy as there is no way of transforming Vbat to Vled.  If you use eg Alkaline cells then 3 in series give about 4.5V (actually 4.9 for a small while) when new and 3 to 3.3V (depending on LED) when exhausted. Potential efficiency is twice or more as good as 9v Bat. Modern alkalines have shelf life of well over 5 years. | Rough calculations suggest that a good modern low Vf white LED (about 2.9V) and 3 x AAA alkaline should allow a good flash for 5 years.

Comment: To measure low current use two large low leakage caps separated by about (1 MegOhm)/(uA drawn) eg 330k for 3 uA, 2 Meg for 0.5 uA etc. This will then drop V = !R = about 1V. Measure with eg 10 MOhm DMM and calculate Vactual based on impedances. Adding a temporary series R to meter will show effective meter resiostance. eg adding a series 10 Meg will halve meter reading if Rmeter = 10 meg. If Caps are large enough temporarily adding meter to flasher side to measure Vcap will not change Vcap much.

Comment: For a forum that supports discussion and people who may love to take up this general challenge look at http://www.piclist.com (don't be put off by the presentation or the PIC in the name). Then visit http://mailman.mit.edu/mailman/listinfo/piclist and join the mailing list and say hello. Provide as much detail of your requirements and problems as possible. 
 Just like here, there are people there who know almost everything (collectively), and are allowed to discuss anything conversationally. Some members of this group are also PICList members (myself included).

Answer (score 2):

(Because this is on the unanswered list...)

This is just too outrageous to recommend.  There are better ways of making efficient flashers, and with the resistor in the power lead, this one is going to be problematical.

Answer (score 0):

They don't make the LM3909 anymore. Or they do, sorta... it's available as the NTE876. That old part used a ‘flying capacitor’ approach to boost up the LED voltage. It was popular in traffic barrier flashers some 40 years ago. Even if you don’t use this part it gives an idea on how to do what you’re trying to do so it’s worth studying.

At any rate this page shows an interesting and efficient ‘joule thief’ flyback approach to blinking an LED. This is another popular project. Link: https://www.electroschematics.com/10896/nostalgic-led-driver-upshot/

Answer (score 0):

As a design approach, one way to reduce average operating current and extend the battery life is to use the charge in the large timing capacitor to light the LED.  When the cap voltage hits a certain level, it is switched to the LED and discharges through it.  This is a variation of a relaxation or hysteretic oscillator.

This can be done with a dual CMOS open-drain comparator, such as a TS393.  8 pins instead of 14, no external FETs.

I think the 3909 did this, but it's been too long.